# How to deal with footprints in shared workspaces in Altium?

Tags: altium, footprint

I am in a university project and we use a shared workspace. Now I have to redo a PCB from a project done by a fellow a few years ago but when I open the project in my computer, it says that there are no footprint libraries found. I though that by uploading the project to the cloud, the libraries would be uploaded too but it doesn't seem to be so. Do I need to replace every component one by one to a component with an existing footprint? Also, how can I prevent it from happening again? Is there a tool to upload every component I use to the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the component and footprints used in the project from the design files.

Something like design->make integrated library (I don't have Altium in front of me atm, just Kicad) Then you can open a new project with the integrated library and  save them separately (which is usually preferable).

See one of Robert Feranec's excellent video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhuHE9b4C_8), but keep in mind that Altium shuffles things around a bit from version to version. I learned more from his videos than from some rather expensive training at Altium in California, to be honest.